# Table contents not centered in SI table format with uncertainty

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

When I use the SI table format, I usually have the numbers centered below the column name. However, when I add some uncertainty part, the contents appear left aligned (or maybe centered on the decimal separator of the uncertainty part?) in the following table:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Some caption.}
    \label{tab:MyTab}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=4.0]S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=3.0]S[table-format=3.1 \pm 1.1, separate-uncertainty]}
    \toprule
    Architecture & {Tile size} & {BS} & {Epochs} & {Seconds per epoch}\\
    \midrule
    U-Net & 1024 & 4 & 100 & 10\\
        & 512 & 8 & 120 & 198.9 \pm 6.6\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Table output]

Is there a way to align the numbers more beautifully, i.e., centered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want `table-parse-only`, e.g.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{Some caption.}
    \label{tab:MyTab}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=4]S[table-format=2]
      S[table-format=3]S[separate-uncertainty, table-parse-only]}
    \toprule
    Architecture & {Tile size} & {BS} & {Epochs} & {Seconds per epoch}\\
    \midrule
    U-Net & 1024 & 4 & 100 & 10\\
        & 512 & 8 & 120 & 198.9 \pm 6.6\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!